# Usage of the Array-method "some": Receiving unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I have tried this:

```
var user = [37, 2, 987, 53, 3322, 12, 9];

function check(item) {
    console.log(item + ' has type ' + typeof item);

    if (item !== 'number') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(user.some(check));
/* Result:
    37 has type number 
    true
*/
```

I expect false as result because the array contains only numbers.
It says inside the function that the element is a number and one line it is something else.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `typeof` to condition, like so

```
if (typeof item !== 'number') {}
```

```js
var user = [37, 2, 987, 53, 3322, 12, 9];

function check(item) {
    if (typeof item !== 'number') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(user.some(check));
```

Also, you can simplify your code, like so

```js
var user = [37, 2, 987, 53, 3322, 12, 9];

function check(item) {
   return (typeof item !== 'number');
}

console.log(user.some(check));
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `typeof` to your condition:

Like here:

```
console.log(item + ' has type ' + typeof item);
```

Add `typeof` here:

```
if (typeof item !== 'number') {
```

You can make that whole `check`function a lot shorter too:

```
function check(item) {
    return typeof item !== 'number';
}
```

This works because `typeof item !== 'number'`, used in your `if`, is already the boolean value you want to return.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.